# Node.js API REST security

Tags: node.js, api, security, rest

I was trying to implement some sort of security in an node.js rest api, either using tokens, avoiding oauth, which is the easiest option?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [passport http bear](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer)? This would allow you to secure your api end points.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into http://passportjs.org/ This is the lib I often see when looking at examples.

Answer (score 0):

Which Node Framework are you using? Have you looked at https://www.npmjs.org/package/iron for tokens Authorization and/or Bell for Authentication https://www.npmjs.org/package/bell ?